# How do we initialise unpacked arrays in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Suppose I declare an unpacked array of size say 8 bits wide.

```
reg b[7:0];
```

If I want to assign b[7] = 1,b[6] = 1, b[5] = 1, ......b[0] = 1, then apart from assigning value to each bit is there a way to assign any combination of bits say 8'bA8, to b?

For instance if I execute this code(below) in verilog:

```
module tb();
    reg [7:0]a;
    reg b[7:0];
    initial begin
        $monitor("a = %b,b = ",a);
        a = 8'hA8;
        b = 8'hA8; // Line 7
    end
endmodule
```

I get this error:

```
C:\iverilog\bin>iverilog -o a test.v
test.v:7: error: Cannot assign to array b. Did you forget a word index?
1 error(s) during elaboration.
```

I am using Icarus Verilog on a command prompt on Windows 10 operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, `b[7:0]` means an array of eight 1-bit numbers. In your example you are trying to initialise it with a single 8-bit number, which is not the same thing.

---

For Verilog, you have to initialise each element in the array one by one:

```
b[0] = 1'b0;
b[1] = 1'b0;
b[2] = ...
```

You could also use a `for`-loop and `localparam` to initialise it, by storing the packed initialisation value in the `localparam`, then using the `for`-loop to copy it in to your unpacked array. As a bonus, the loop can be parameterised allowing you to change the size of the variable if you desire.

```
integer i;
localparam b_init = 8'hA8;
initial begin
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
        b[i] = b_init[i];
    end
end
```

You could also try `$readmemb` or `$readmemh` if your synth tool supports it to load a binary or hex file of eight 1-bit numbers.

---

For SystemVerilog, you can do array initialisation:

```
reg b [7:0] = '{1'b1, 1'b0, 1'b1, ...};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a packed array to initialize b to 8'hA8.

```
module tb();
    reg [7:0]a;
    reg b[7:0];
    reg [7:0] temp;
    integer i=0;
    initial begin
        $monitor("a = %b,b = ",a);
        a = 8'hA8;
        temp = a;   // temp = 8'hA8;
        while(i<8) begin
           b[i] = temp[i];
           i=i+1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```